# How can i add registered date my form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, registration

I want to add last registered date my registration form in Javascript.

Here is my Javascript code...

```
function addHtmlTableRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table"),
        newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
        cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
        cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
        cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
        cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3),        
        name = document.getElementById("name").value,
        surname = document.getElementById("surname").value,
        email = document.getElementById("email").value,
        password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = surname;
    cell3.innerHTML = email;
    cell4.innerHTML = password;
    cell5.innerHTML = date;
}
```

This is my full [code](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/ZRENNZ)

Thanks for help...

Comment: if you google get current date and javascript, you should be well on your way. if that doesn't help, rephrase your question so it is more clear what you want to do...

Comment: currentDate = new Date()

Comment: So you want to get the date (and time) of the last instance of someone registering on your site?

Comment: i mean, i want when people register my site, javascript will show that register date. my english not so good. sorry :(

Comment: yeah stephan that's what i mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function addHtmlTableRow() {

    var table = document.getElementById("table"),
        newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
        cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
        cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
        cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
        cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3), 
        cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4),    
        name = document.getElementById("name").value,
        surname = document.getElementById("surname").value,
        email = document.getElementById("email").value,
        password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var month = new Date().getMonth() +1;
    var dated = new Date().getDate() +"/"+ month+"/"+new Date().getFullYear();
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = surname;
    cell3.innerHTML = email;
    cell4.innerHTML = password;
    cell5.innerHTML = dated;

}
```

Comment: okay this is good, but not alerted , register date must show in date under 'td' .